# php cookie or session for viewed details?

Tags: php, cookies

i have data from database and i need to count the views for every click,

i need to count only unique click for the current hour.

saving it in database is not in my options. and for the user to know that he/she already click that data

should i use cookie for every data that users clicked or session?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it in a session, there is no need to send it back and forth with every page request, that would only slow things down, especially if the site is big and the internet connection of your visitor slow.

However, note that you can only display this information to your visitor if you use sessions or cookies, there is nothing that **you** can actually do with it unless you store in in a database or a text file.

Comment: is it advisable to use this if i need to store all the id of the data that users clicked? , if user clicked 100 data so i need to save it into session every id>?

Comment: Oh, if you're storing loads of data, definitely go for sessions. You don't want all that overhead on every request you do.

Comment: @Efaz AÑecoh J-ra Yes, but what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: the thing i need to do is i have to list down all the persons data and the company needs to view the personal data so if they already click it, i need to mark that person data as viewed.